# What does "the greatest translation in any language" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "In 1713, Alexander Pope began his translation of the Iliad, a work
>   that took him seven years to complete and that literary critic Samuel
>   Johnson, Pope's contemporary, pronounced the greatest translation in
>   any language."

This is a GMAT question.  I am curious about the last part of the sentence.  What does "the greatest translation in any language" mean?  Does it mean Samuel Johnson was fluent in all languages of the world and had compared the translation of the Iliad to every other translation work that ever existed at that time?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a literary device that is called **hyperbole**.

When somebody is described as "the most beautiful woman on earth", the speaker probably has *not* seen all 3,5 billion women on earth. 
However, the speaker thinks that the woman is so beautiful, it must be (almost) impossible that any woman is more beautiful.

Likewise, Johnson did *not* know all languages, and had *not* examined all translations, but he simply found Pope's translation so great, that he deemed it near impossible that any greater one would exist.

Comment: [Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Johnson) was so prolific, I'd almost be willing to believe it of him.

Comment: In 1720, I'd wager the _Iliad_ had only been translated into a handful.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's not clear whether Pope only meant translations _of the Iliad_. Even if he did, it is unlikely he has actually read every single translation that ever had been made into Latin or Arabic (A _lot_ of classical Greek works were translated into Arabic during what is know as the Dark Ages in Europe).

Comment: @oerkelens I assume you mean Johnson. Though I'm not contesting your 'hyperbole' label. //  Perhaps there were other critics whose opinions he relied upon. In any case, it's quite a claim to make (but he was quite an authority).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes indeed, it was Johnson's claim of course. It's true that some people reach such a position of authority one would (almost) take their hyperbole at face value. Sometimes this is actually done to _undermine_ one's authority, by (falsely) assuming that no hyperbole was employed: "Johnson made an impossible claim, so why would we trust what he says?" Which in itself, of course, is a _straw man_.

Comment: Has any person suggested a 'greater' translation since? (We may safely ignore any such claims by Monty Python etc.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Into specific languages, yes. I am not sure whether such claims took into account Johnson's claim of all languages.

Comment: Meaning 'overall greatest, into any other language than the original' (and hence 'greater than Pope's').